# Posting object from React.js to PHP using Axios

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, forms, axios

I am trying to create a login form using React JS as frontend and PHP as backend. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the form's data (email and password) to the PHP script. I tried googling and all the solutions either don't work for me or are out of data. I am using React v16.

This is my front-end code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// libraries
import { Col, 
          Button, 
          Form, 
          FormGroup, 
          Label, 
          Input} from 'reactstrap';
import Axios from 'axios'          


const App = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const submit = () => {
    Axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:80/api/login.php',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: {
        email,
        password
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>

      <Form>
        <FormGroup row>
          <Label for="exampleEmail" sm={2}>Email</Label>
          <Col sm={10}>
            <Input value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup row>
          <Label for="examplePassword" sm={2}>Password</Label>
          <Col sm={10}>
            <Input value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup check row>
          <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
            <Button onClick={submit}>Submit</Button>
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>
      </Form>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my backend:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo "received data";
print_r("$data");

?>
```

For now, if I look at Chrome inspector, it will say **Request Payload** is {email: "xxx", password: "xxx"} so I know my front end is trying to send data to `login.php` but I don't know how to "catch" the data sent by the front end with PHP.

What I intended to do is: once `login.php` gets the data, it will return a JSON object of the data and the string `"received data"` back to the frontend.

Please help me take a look at this. I did research all day and still can't find a solution.

FYI, I have been trying every solution I can find online for example I tried this:

```
let data = {
      email,
      password
    }

let form = new FormData()
form.append('data', data)

Axios.post('http://localhost:80/api/login.php', form)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

and the backend will be:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Please check your API URL is it correct? `URL: 'http://localhost:80/api/login.php` i think something is missing on port

Comment: @SanatGupta it is correct. I am running  ```login.php``` on Wamp server and the port is indeed 80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi please just replace your Php code I hope you will get your response.

Thanks

```
<php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Content-type:application/json");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo "received data";
    print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: @Jonathan Please have a look answer you just need to replace your PHP code you will get your response. actually you need to allow the cors domain for your API access. Thanks

Comment: what does all the header functions do?

Comment: btw it works now. I now get response from the login.php api. Thank you so much

Comment: All headers are allowed your requested domain

Comment: Sounds good your work is done please up vote mark as answer thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin Please read about cors allow origin.

Comment: One more question. If I link, for example, ```signup.php``` like this, won't it have a major security issue? Like people can just find my ```signup.php``` API link and spam me with tons of fake accounts. Is there any way I can hide my API link and make it hidden from other people?

Comment: You just need to replace * into your domain it means your base URL From which URL you hitting that API . i hope Your API will be access only for your domain what you add on that header ’header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');’